# ut ubox vs 2000 ecg machine Data values

Tags: .net

I am working on ut ubox vs 2000 ecg machine.
this ecg machine trnsfer its data in byte array form
as on LAN(Local Area Network) given below.

How can i get the ecg wave value from this array.

My code is as below.but i cannot get the actual value.

```
byte[] tst = {0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xCF, 0xFC, 0xFF, 0xDF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFD, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE };

string strresult = "";
for (int j = 0; j < tst.Length-1; j+=2)
{
    strHex = String.Format("{0:x2}", tst[j]);
    strHex += String.Format("{0:x2}", tst[j + 1]);
    strresult = strresult + "," + short.Parse(strHex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}

Console.WriteLine(strresult);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to convert an Array of Bytes (8 Bit) to an Array of Words (16 Bit)?

Try the [BitConverter.ToUInt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint16) Method, it takes two Bytes from an Array and returns an int16 aka short

```
for (int j = 0; j < tst.Length-1; j+=2){
    strresult = strresult + "," + BitConverter.ToUInt16( tst, j ).toString();
}
```

Select the preferred Method (toUInt16 or toInt16 depending on signed or unsigned values and watch out for [little or big endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), you might have to switch the Byte Order at some point.

(code not tested for syntax)